# Kubernetes - PVC not binding the NFS PV

Tags: kubernetes

I created a physical volume using NFS and PVC for the same volume. However, the PVC always creates a EBS disk storage instead of binding to the PV. Please see the log below:

```
> kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
mynfspv   100Gi      RWX           Retain          Available                                      7s
```

create PVC now

```
> kubectl get pvc
NAME       STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mynfspvc   Bound     pvc-a081c470-3f23-11e7-9d30-024e42ef6b60   100Gi      RWX           default        4s


> kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM              STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
mynfspv                                    100Gi      RWX           Retain          Available                                               50s
pvc-a081c470-3f23-11e7-9d30-024e42ef6b60   100Gi      RWX           Delete          Bound       default/mynfspvc   default                  17s
```

nfs-pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mynfspv
  labels:
    name: nfs2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: dbc56.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    path: /
```

nfs-pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mynfspvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have dynamic provisioning and default storageclass feature enabled, and the default class is AWS ebs. You can check your default class with following command:

```
$ kubectl get storageclasses
NAME                 TYPE
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
```

If this is correct, then I think you'll need to specify storage class to solve you problem.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-class
provisioner: kubernetes.io/fake-nfs
```

Add `storageClassName` to both of your PV

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mynfspvc
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs-class
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

and PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mynfspv
  labels:
    name: nfs2
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs-class
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: dbc56.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    path: /
```

You can check out https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1 for details.

Comment: I got it worked since I asked the question by just adding storageClassName for both PV and PVC. However, I did not add the storage class itself as you suggested. In a nutshell, the system has only one storage class which is default to aws-ebs. By adding a storageClassName attribute to PV and PVC, I got it working. It is confusing to me based on the documentation.  There is an example here - https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_glusterfs.html. This uses GlusterFS but the storageClassName is not set in the PV or PVC. I wonder how this works.

Comment: I'm always using a storageclass along with PV/PVC, but it's possible to just bind PV/PVC without storageclass.  I don't see it documented neither; I guess it's because this setup is not a recommended approach.  To fully understand how storageclass and PV/PVC binding works, I suggest going through the source for truth :)

Finding PV: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/755d368c4a2865f3572f7eacfcedd252776227ee/pkg/controller/volume/persistentvolume/index.go#L73

Plugin:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/admission/storageclass/default/admission.go#L80

Comment: This is exactly what I encountered on k8s 1.7.  It's worth mentioning that I had to delete the PVCs & PVs that were not working, then had to kill all pods that were trying to hook to the PVC, then re-create the PVs and PVCs.  I had to repeat this cycle 2-3 types before the PVCs were able to get a lock on the PVs, so be sure to hit it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Kube is this ? The root cause is as mentioned by @ddysher. In your setup the "Default" Storage class is "EBS" as you can see in the get pv{c} outputs. According to kube version you can also make use of 'calim selector' in PVC spec. Refer # https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/volume-selectors.md

Comment: I am using 1.6.4. Please see my comment in response to @ddysher. I got it worked by just adding storageClassName in PV and PVC. However, I still have only one storage class which is aws-ebs.